# 'isGooglePlayServicesAvailable'(this) is deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm following a tutuorial to use google location services. So, I'm trying to get location using Google API service. But I got `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`(this) is deprecated error. Can anyone help. Thanks

Below is my code for checking if Play services exist on device:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices(){
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)){
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please just use a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When you **looked at the documentation** for [`GooglePlayServicesUtil`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) (you did that, right?), the following didn't appear obvious to you? *This method was deprecated. Use [`GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) instead.*

Answer (score 94):

Use [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) instead

```
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context)
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of checking if play services are available is:

```
private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context) {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
```